# Remove duplicates from json data

Tags: python

Is there an efficient way to remove duplicates 'person_id' fields from this data with python? In this case just keep the first occurrence.

```
{
  {obj_id: 123,
    location: {
      x: 123,
      y: 323,
  },
  {obj_id: 13,
    location: {
      x: 23,
      y: 333,
  },
 {obj_id: 123,
    location: {
      x: 122,
      y: 133,
  },
}
```

Should become:

```
{
  {obj_id: 123,
    location: {
      x: 123,
      y: 323,
  },
  {obj_id: 13,
    location: {
      x: 23,
      y: 333,
  },
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid json. Can you post your actual data?

Comment: Also, those aren't really duplicates...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presuming your JSON is valid syntax and you are indeed requesting help for `Python` you will need to do something like this

```
import json
ds = json.loads(json_data_string) #this contains the json
unique_stuff = { each['obj_id'] : each for each in ds }.values()
```

if you want to always retain the first occurrence, you will need to do something like this

```
all_ids = [ each['obj_id'] for each in ds ] # get 'ds' from above snippet
unique_stuff = [ ds[ all_ids.index(id) ] for id in set(ids) ]
```

Comment: Assuming, ``ds`` is an array of dictionaries (as that's the option that makes most sense) this works well, but keeps the last occurrence instead of the first one.

Comment: +1: elegant (the first example). Though `.values()`/`set()` may return objects in any order. Assuming the input is json array then it might matter. Here's [order preserving algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17076805/4279)

Comment: micro-nitpick: `obj` and `json_array` might be better names than `each` and `ds`

Comment: whats the difference between `json.loads(...)` and `json.load(...)`?

Comment: @Sevenearths `json.loads(...)` loads from string (loads:load string); `json.load(...)` loads from a file handler (or a `read()` supporting file-like object)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an implementation that preserves order of input json objects and keeps the first occurrence of objects with the same id:

```
import json
import sys
from collections import OrderedDict

L = json.load(sys.stdin, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
seen = OrderedDict()
for d in L:
    oid = d["obj_id"]
    if oid not in seen:
        seen[oid] = d

json.dump(seen.values(), sys.stdout,  indent=2)
```

#### Input

```
[
  {
    "obj_id": 123, 
    "location": {
      "x": 123, 
      "y": 323
    }
  }, 
  {
    "obj_id": 13, 
    "location": {
      "x": 23, 
      "y": 333
    }
  }, 
  {
    "obj_id": 123, 
    "location": {
      "x": 122, 
      "y": 133
    }
  }
]
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/rHsEKC)

```
[
  {
    "obj_id": 123, 
    "location": {
      "x": 123, 
      "y": 323
    }
  }, 
  {
    "obj_id": 13, 
    "location": {
      "x": 23, 
      "y": 333
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score -3):

(if you had valid json)

```
from simplejson import loads, dumps
dumps(loads(my_json))
```

Comment: How can you know it will do anything, if you don't know how the correct input looks like?

Comment: The question title is "Remove duplicates from json data". I caveat'd "if valid json" and provided an answer. This is what everyone else in the question has also done.

Answer (score -4):

This is not valid JSON. On a valid JSON (Array), You can use jQuery $.each and look at the Obj_id to find and remove duplicates.

Something like this:

```
$.each(myArrayOfObjects, function(i, v)
{
      // check for duplicate and add non-repeatings to a new array
});
```

Comment: You missed the ``python`` tag. Not every things in the world is jQuery.