# Merge cells in html table for duplicate data in python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, merge, html-table

I am creating an HTML table in python. I generated the HTML table from json data using **json2html** package. Now i am having the HTML table in a object. I need to merge the repetitive cells in each column that is i need to merge continuous cells having same data. Is there a way or package to merge cells in a generated HTML table? Please give an solution. Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to remove duplicates, you can check out this: [Remove duplicates from json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076345/remove-duplicates-from-json-data). I'd recommend removing the duplicates before converting to html because it's much easier to process dictionaries/json than an html table in python. However, I am confused by you wanting to merge them when you say they have the same data-wouldn't you just want to remove the duplicate?

Comment: yes removing duplicates is easier than merging the duplicates to one. will try it.