# Group duplicate JSON values in Python and construct Key Value pairs

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of computers in an array.  I would like to aggregate entries with identical IP addresses and create an array called `data` and append the duplicates there.  Below is an example of the input and desired output.  I have tried a couple different options, but can't find a solution.

Input

```json
[
    {
        "name": "computera",
        "Computer_Name": "computera",
        "Serial_Number": "computera",
        "IP_Address": "8.8.8.8"
    },
    {
        "name": "computerb",
        "Computer_Name": "computerb",
        "Serial_Number": "computerb",
        "IP_Address": "8.8.8.8"
    },
    {
        "name": "computerc",
        "Computer_Name": "computerc",
        "Serial_Number": "computerc",
        "IP_Address": "1.2.3.4"
    }
]
```

Desired output

```json
{
    "ip": "8.8.8.8",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "computera",
            "Computer_Name": "computera",
            "Serial_Number": "computera",
            "IP_Address": "8.8.8.8"
        },
        {
            "name": "computerb",
            "Computer_Name": "computerb",
            "Serial_Number": "computerb",
            "IP_Address": "8.8.8.8"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "ip": "1.2.3.4",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "computerc",
            "Computer_Name": "computerc",
            "Serial_Number": "computerc",
            "IP_Address": "1.2.3.4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: def group_computers_by_ip(computers):
    grouped_computers = {}
    
    for computer in computers:
        ip_address = computer["IP_Address"]
        
        if ip_address in grouped_computers:
            grouped_computers[ip_address].append(computer)
        else:
            grouped_computers[ip_address] = [computer]
    
    return grouped_computers

Comment: Thanks.  This groups by IP address and is very similar to the link below, but it doesn't create the needed key 'ip'.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404154/find-duplicates-in-json-using-python